# Implementing paging upon injecting DATA into DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, dom

I have a function which does a jquery post like followin:

```
   function PostAndUpdate(_username) {
            $.post("/SearchCompetitor/Index", { username: _username }, StartLoading())
                               .done(function (data) {
                                   if (data !== "UsernameError") {
                                       StopLoading();
                                       var brands = $('<table />').append(data).find('#tableProducts').html();
                                       $('#tableProducts').html(brands);

                                       var header = $('<div />').append(data).find('.bs-glyphicons').html();
                                       $('.bs-glyphicons').html(header);
                                       $('#tableProducts thead, #header').fadeIn("slow");
                                       $('#emptyText').hide();


                                   }
                                   else {
                                       StopLoading();
                                       ShowMessage("No eBay user was found under: " + $('.txtSearch').val());
                                   }
                               })
                               .fail(function (data) {
                                   StopLoading();
                                   ShowMessage("Something went wrong, please try again!");
                               });
        }
```

I'm trying to figure out ideas how to implement paging before injecting all the data into the browser's DOM;

This is because sometimes I'm injecting 2000-5000 items into the DOM and breaking the data into smaller chunks and then enabling the paging in page...

So before the data is injected into the DOM like this:

```
   var brands = $('<table />').append(data).find('#tableProducts').html();
                                           $('#tableProducts').html(brands);
```

I'd like to first somehow filter out first 100 elements of the tableProducts, inject them , and later on enable the paging itself...

Is his doable without sending any extra data to the server itself or ?

Comment: Have you considered using a plugin like DataTables?  It can do exactly what you are looking for with very little code :) https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: @Dana I'm trying it right now as we speak, but there is an Issue, when I load the data inside the table itself, once I try to use it's features , it's completely unresponsive, the built-in features are unresponsive... One moment I'll update my question tos how you how I did it